# How to parse JSON data into object instance in Bridge.NET?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing, bridge.net

I am working on a **Bridge.NET** project that dynamically creates Bootstrap forms based on template data. The data are received as JSON through a `jQuery.Ajax` call.

The problem is, upon successful reception I cannot convert the JSON data back to their object representation, for example:

```
Form form = Bridge.Html5.JSON.Parse<Form>((string)data);
```

where **Form** is a class describing a bootstrap form, something like:

```
public class Form
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Field[] Fields { get; set;  }
}
```

The above line builds but the generated JavaScript behaves like `form` is not instantiated, so the code below fails:

```
var title = form.Title;
```

Anybody has any idea or workaround on how to make it work?

Comment: Good question. This might be the place to use the `[ObjectLiteral]` attribute on the `Form` class. I'll have to run a few tests to confirm.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a full code sample that works as expected with the latest release of Bridge.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following sample demonstrates the full scenario.

**Example**

```
using Bridge;
using Bridge.Html5;

namespace Demo
{
    public class App
    {
        [Ready]
        public static void Main()
        {
            var data = "{ \"title\": \"testing\" }";
            Form form = JSON.Parse<Form>(data);

            Console.Log(form.Title); // logs "testing"
        }
    }

    public class Form
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The following is emitted by the compiler:

```
Bridge.define('Demo.App', {
    statics: {
        config: {
            init: function () {
                Bridge.ready(this.main);
            }
        },
        main: function () {
            var data = "{ \"title\": \"testing\" }";
            var form = Bridge.merge(new Demo.Form(), JSON.parse(data));

            console.log(form.getTitle()); // logs "testing"
        }
    }
});

Bridge.define('Demo.Form', {
    config: {
        properties: {
            Title: null
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @dpant - With the latest release of Bridge.NET (v1.1), your original scenario should be working as expected.